# Popup LOV or Retutn P_Iten (If P_tem is in the Popup LOV list)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a normal window with a table fill form, there is a variable P3_VAL. In this variable, I select a barcode from the LOV_ list, I want to add a barcode reader along with the camera (I use a plugin). To do this, I add a barcode button to the form. After that I need to go to the modal window where the "7" window with the camera opens, the barcode is read and added to the variable P7_NEW, after which I want to click the "Add value" button in the modal window to move the value from P7_NEW to P3_VAL ( the plugin works but I can't pass this value, so the P3_VAL source is LOV_list when I set the text type P3_VAL, everything works). I want the value I pass from the modal window to be written to P3_VAL if it is in LOV_list, here is my situation!
That's how I return the value from the modal window: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex-tips-return-a-value-from-a-modal-dialog
 Here is my request for LOV_list:

```html
select c.SEAL_NUMBER d,

c.SEAL_NUMBER r

from SEC_SEALS c

where it does not exist (select null

from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING r

where r.SEAL_NUMBER = c.SEAL_NUMBER

)

order c.SEAL_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `where it does not exist` or just `order` (without a `by` keyword) are not valid Oracle SQL syntax.

Your LOV query should be written like this:

```
select c.SEAL_NUMBER d,
       c.SEAL_NUMBER r
  from SEC_SEALS c
where not exists (select 1
                    from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING r
                   where r.SEAL_NUMBER = c.SEAL_NUMBER
                     and rownum = 1
)
order by c.SEAL_NUMBER;
```

If there's still an error after this correction, please copy it in your question and I'll try to help you further.